# Can I get the matched DOM string with PHP and DOMDocument?

Tags: php, domdocument

I've got my HTML inside of `$html`.

```
dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);


$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$tags = $xpath->query('//div[@id="header"]');


foreach($tags as $tag) {

    var_dump($tag->nodeValue); // the innerHTML of that element
    var_dump($tag); // object(DOMElement)#3 (0) { }

}
```

Is there a way to get that node, or remove it?

Basically, I'm parsing an existing website and need to remove elements from it. What method do I call to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [DOMNode::removeChild](http://is.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) ?